# How to disable running checkstyle and only do it on demand

Tags: java, gradle, checkstyle

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/checkstyle_plugin.html

How to disable running checkstyle during `./gradlew build` and only do it on demand via `./gradlew checkstyleMain`

```
checkstyle {
    showViolations = false
    ignoreFailures = true
    maxWarnings = 0
    maxErrors = 0
    configFile = file("checkstyle.xml")
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will disable `checkstyleMain` task from being executed until it's explicitly called from command line:

```
checkstyleMain {
    enabled = gradle.startParameter.taskNames.contains('checkstyleMain')
}
```

Comment: It stops the build command to disable checkstyle checks. But ./gradlew checkstyleMain doesn't do anything

Comment: It works for me, are You sure that there isn't any other reason why `checkstyleMain` doesn't do anything? Try to execute `./gradlew clean && ./gradlew checkstyleMain -i` and check what it says for `checkstyleMain` task.